# navbar hide and show toggle on smaller screen messes up bigger screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been trying to make my navbar collapsible using Flexbox. I got the navbar to toggle correctly when the screen's smaller. But when you hide the nav items on smaller screen then make the screen larger, the nav items wont't show up. If I leave it open while the screen's smaller then make the screen larger, nav items' flex direction's set to column which I don't want when the screen's larger.

Here's my code:

```js
$(".toggle-btn").click(function() {
  $(".nav-toggle").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```css
/* header */

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: #FFB600;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 20px #48493e;
  z-index: 1;
}

header ul {
  display: flex;
}


/*slide menu*/

.nav-btn {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 3.5em 4em 0 0;
}

.toggle-btn {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  width: 4em;
  height: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 1px #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 2px #000;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.toglge-btn:active {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 1px #000;
  top: 2px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 820px) {
  header {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .nav-brand {
    align-self: flex-start;
  }
  .nav-btn {
    display: block;
  }
  header ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-items {
    line-height: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <h2 class="nav-brand"><a href="/"> Tequila Grill</a></h2>
  <div class="nav-btn">
    <button class="toggle-btn">Menu</button>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav-toggle">
    <li><a class="nav-items" href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-items" href="/menu">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-items" href="/hours">Hours</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-items" href="/location">Location</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-items" href="/catering">Catering</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go bro

```
@media all and (min-width: 821px) {
  ul.nav-toggle[style] {
    display:flex!important;
  }
  }
```

This will tell it to add the style `display:flex;` on all view-port sizes `821px` and larger. The `[style]` selector inserts the css inline like your JS.

https://jsfiddle.net/ud8fqxmL/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
function resiz() {
  $(".toggle-btn").click(function() {
    $(".nav-toggle").slideToggle("slow");
  });
}
resiz();

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  resiz();
});
```

it will works